open vpn - not working but also dont returns any error
i have both open vpn server and client. the client is my windows pc and the server is a ubuntu 22 VPS.
im running openvpn on the serverside with this command :
openvpn --dev tun --ifconfig 172.16.0.1 172.16.0.2 --cipher AES-256-CBC --secret static-OpenVPN.key

and the client tunnel with this command :
./openvpn --remote 141.11.184.71 --dev tun --ifconfig 172.16.0.1 172.16.0.2 --cipher AES-256-CBC --secret C:\Users\98912\Desktop\key.key

both client and server dont show any errors but the successful connection message is not shown on client side even after waiting for minutes
clientside output:
2024-06-22 13:07:35 DEPRECATED OPTION: The option --secret is deprecated.                                                                                                                    2024-06-22 13:07:35 DEPRECATION: No tls-client or tls-server option in configuration detected. OpenVPN 2.7 will remove the functionality to run a VPN without TLS. See the examples section in the manual page for examples of a similar quick setup with peer-fingerprint.                                                                                                               2024-06-22 13:07:35 OpenVPN 2.6.11 [git:v2.6.11/ddf6bf6d2a135835] Windows [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [PKCS11] [AEAD] [DCO] built on Jun 20 2024                                             
2024-06-22 13:07:35 Windows version 10.0 (Windows 10 or greater), amd64 executable                                                                                                           2024-06-22 13:07:35 library versions: OpenSSL 3.3.1 4 Jun 2024, LZO 2.10                                                                                                                     2024-06-22 13:07:35 DCO version: 1.2.1                                                                                                                                                       2024-06-22 13:07:35 open_tun                                                                                                                                                                 2024-06-22 13:07:35 tap-windows6 device [OpenVPN TAP-Windows6] opened                                                                                                                        2024-06-22 13:07:35 Notified TAP-Windows driver to set a DHCP IP/netmask of 172.16.0.1/255.255.255.252 on interface {CA5D7BF3-0797-4C14-8B7B-B0DC854B6865} [DHCP-serv: 172.16.0.2, lease-time: 31536000]                                                                                                                                                                                  2024-06-22 13:07:35 Successful ARP Flush on interface [42] {CA5D7BF3-0797-4C14-8B7B-B0DC854B6865}                                                                                            2024-06-22 13:07:35 IPv4 MTU set to 1500 on interface 42 using SetIpInterfaceEntry()                                                                                                         2024-06-22 13:07:35 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]141.11.184.71:1194                                                                                            2024-06-22 13:07:35 UDPv4 link local (bound): [AF_INET][undef]:1194                                                                                                                          2024-06-22 13:07:35 UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]141.11.184.71:1194

server side output:
2024-06-22 20:37:05 Cipher negotiation is disabled since neither P2MP client nor server mode is enabled
2024-06-22 20:37:05 OpenVPN 2.5.9 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Sep 29 2023
2024-06-22 20:37:05 library versions: OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022, LZO 2.10
2024-06-22 20:37:05 TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
2024-06-22 20:37:05 net_iface_mtu_set: mtu 1500 for tun0
2024-06-22 20:37:05 net_iface_up: set tun0 up
2024-06-22 20:37:05 net_addr_ptp_v4_add: 172.16.0.1 peer 172.16.0.2 dev tun0
2024-06-22 20:37:05 Could not determine IPv4/IPv6 protocol. Using AF_INET
2024-06-22 20:37:05 UDPv4 link local (bound): [AF_INET][undef]:1194
2024-06-22 20:37:05 UDPv4 link remote: [AF_UNSPEC]

edit: something is making it more weird. sometimes like one time in one hour or so it works. but every time i check my ip is the original one. also the client dont shows the succes msg

You have the same setting for client and server:
--ifconfig 172.16.0.1 172.16.0.2

Swap the ifconfig values for either client or server - but not both:
--ifconfig 172.16.0.2 172.16.0.1


i cant understand. what should i do?

i modified the client command to this: ./openvpn --remote 141.11.184.71 --dev tun --ifconfig 172.16.0.2 172.16.0.1 --cipher AES-256-CBC --secret C... but its stil not working

@amacoder have you opened the appropriate port and protocol in the firewall on your VPS Server? Or are you using port forwarding on your home(?) router to allow traffic to your Windows PC? You need at least one set to allow the OpenVPN traffic inbound otherwise the two systems will block each other

I'd allowed it in firewall and im installing it on a VPS so i think its port forwarded already
